# How i can display my google calendar events in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
void getCalendarEvents(DateTime t1,DateTime t2) async {
    DateTime start = t1.subtract(new Duration(days: 10)).toUtc ();
    DateTime end = t1.subtract(new Duration(days: 9)).toUtc ();
    final authHeaders = await _currentUser.authHeaders;
    final httpClient = new GoogleHttpClient(authHeaders);
    CalendarApi calendarApi = CalendarApi(httpClient);
    var calEvents = calendarApi.events.list("primary",timeMin: start,timeMax: end,);
    calEvents.then((Events events) {
      events.items.forEach((Event event) {print(event.summary);});
    });
  }
```

I get events in console so how i can display event on the mobile screen.
I want to display event fields like "summary", "description", "location", "start", "end", etc.. on the mobile screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to stock them in a list, like that:

initiate your list at the after the imported library like so:

```
  var val = [];
```

then you stock them like this:

```
  calEvents.then(
      (events) => {events.items.forEach((event) => val.add(event.summary) ) }, ,
      );
```

after, you're able to access the value on the Page you want by calling them like that:

Let's do in a list view for example,

```
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    body: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 8.0, 4, 0),
  child: ListView.separated(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Container(
          height: 50,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text('${val[index]}'),
              ),

            ],
          ),
        );
      },
      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
          const Divider(),
      itemCount: val.length),
));
```

}

Comment: thank you so much for your help, it's works for me.